Is there anything that says I got Ferryman's Clearance by name, after I get it?
I started Dual Evidence and out-of-bounds past the torches in the north of the Great Hall of Truths.
Since that warped me past the Duat Hall waypoint, I thought I was stuck, but thankfully not.
And I think I have the Ferryman's Clearance, if it's the Duat Hall clearance, which I do have?
Is there anything that I can check to make sure I really got the "Ferryman's Clearance" instead of "Duat Hall clearance" just to make sure things are perfectly in-line with the Wiki that says: "Ferryman's Clearance: Granted when starting the Dual Evidence quest."

You could simply believe in the wiki which says you got it at the start of the quest. Why do you have doubt? Does anything not work as intended?

Also, you could look at your stone slate. It's the second lower symbol in the middle column. Looks like an earring.

@ChrᴉzremembersMonica - Yeah, it's the Duat Hall Clearance, but the Wiki never calls it that, always "Ferryman", https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Duat_Hall so I'm wondering if it's ever called "Ferryman" anywhere I can confirm in-game.

You... made quite the mess, didn't you?
First, you mentions abusing glitches in a quest. I won't warn you about the possibility of a ban, I'll just point out that as far as I know in the past it was possible to soft-lock the game by using glitches to play quests out of order, something the players of the "no element traveler" challenge knew quite well.
Second, about the clearance. You don't get it "at the start" of the quest, nor the wiki says that anywhere. You get it after a specific scene and Paimon noticing that something changed on the slate. After that scene the name is briefly displayed the first time you enter the quest specific menu.


Lemme add this link to my question. Thanks for answering! https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Scarlet_Sand_Slate#Hidden_Clearance - "Ferryman's Clearance: Granted when starting the Dual Evidence quest."
